# Независимо от того. Причины обособления

Tags: пунктуация, запятые

Подскажите, пожалуйста, почему "независимо от того" обособляется с двух сторон?

**Мое особое желание заключается в том, чтобы на присуждение премий не влияла национальность кандидата, чтобы премию получали наиболее достойные, независимо от того, скандинавы они или нет.**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Выражение "независимо от" как самостоятельная единица не обособляется, но оно входит в  разные конструкции:

1. **Предлог**: **Независимо от кого-чего**, в зн. предлога. Несмотря на что-л., не принимая во внимание кого-, что-л. Уйти из института **независимо от** желания отца.
2. **Союз**: **Независимо от того что,** в зн. союза. Несмотря на то что; хотя. Явился на работу, **независимо от того** что был болен.

В этом примере составной союз не расчленен.

3. **Предложный оборот с придаточным предложением:** независимо от того, ....

Предложный оборот  с придаточным может обособляться или нет (как и все предложные конструкции):

(1) **Не обособляется,** нет паузы, входит  основное сообщение: «Программы реструктуризации в банке должны **существовать независимо от того,** благоприятная обстановка в экономике или нет. [Дмитрий Бжезинский. Впереди паровоза // «Однако», 2010]

(2) **Обособляется как уточнение**: Они в выигрыше **всегда, независимо от того**, женитесь вы или разводитесь, приобретаете компанию или банкротитесь. [Вадим Бондарь. Всеобщая несостоятельность // «Однако», 2010]

(3) **Факультативное обособление**: Личные эмоции всегда вносят некие помехи, независимо от того, кем является человек ― писателем, великим математиком или физиком… [В. Губарев, Ю. С. Осипов. Академик Юрий Осипов: куда же идет наша наука? // «Наука и жизнь», 2007]

Answer (score 0):

Исправьте опечатку: *Выражение "**незвисимо** от" как самостоятельная единица...*